# React Error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): api_call.json is not a function. Fetch? async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, async.js

I worked on a project for a weather app ( I am a beginner) and when I click on the button to get the weather its not working.

It tells me Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): api_call.json is not a function

Would anyone have an idea of why I have this error?

Thank you,

```js
import React, { Component, } from 'react';
import {Titles, Data, Weather} from "./components";
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {

  state = {
      temperature:undefined,
      city:undefined,
      country:undefined,
      humidity:undefined,
      error:undefined
  }

getWeather = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
 const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
 const country = e.target.elements.country.value;

 const key="48f82148953e62c753c8862a905797b0";
 //const api_call = await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=48f82148953e62c753c8862a905797b0&units=metrics');

 const api_call = ('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + country + '&APPID=' + key + '&units=metrics');


  const data = await api_call.json();

  if (city && country){
    console.log(data);
      this.setState({
        temperature: data.main.temp,
        city: data.name,
        country: data.sys.country,
        humidity: data.main.humidity,
        description: data.weather[0].description,
        error:"",
      });

  } else {
    this.setState({
      temperature: undefined,
      city: undefined,
      country: undefined,
      humidity: undefined,
      description: undefined,
      error:"Please enter the correct name of the city and country code",
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Your `api_call` variable in this example is a string, which certainly has no `.json()` method. But I notice you have a commented out line where you use `fetch`. Is that the line you're actually using when you see this error?

Comment: no that was actually something I tried and didn't work. I tried to use fetch a few different way too but I kept getting error messages. That's the version that breaks my code less so I could work on the styling

Comment: Put `try` `catch` and check what is coming in `catch`.

Comment: Well you definitely need to use `fetch` one way or another. If you use that commented out line instead of the current one, you mentioned you kept getting error messages? Can you say which errors you get from that?

Comment: I get this when I do it Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined (data.main.temp,)